# How can I improve my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I am new here, and I want to be a good part of this community. I read the rules, but I still seem to have made a few mistakes.

I searched for a solution to my problem using search engines and other forums as well as Stack Overflow. I found other people with the same problem, but no real solution.

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34486634/2675154) on iOS development was downvoted.

**I am not complaining about the downvote, asking when downvotes are justified, or asking why I was downvoted.**

Downvotes are a signal that there is something wrong with my question or that my question does not shows any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

**How can I improve my question?**

Comment: I've edited the question in question to capitalize the trademarks, fix some spelling and grammar, remove some unnecessary spacing, reduce some of the noise, clarify, and include the images in the question, and highlight your actual question.

Comment: My only advice at this point is to clarify what you mean by "flow away".

Comment: My guess is that it was the addition of `[Solved]` in the title and adding an answer to your question. That is not how things work on SO as the questions and answers should be distinct.

Comment: Also, you had one downvote period. That's nothing to worry about, especially when you have 3 upvotes. I'd second what BSMP and Martin both said - you select the answer that helps you, not mark it Solved. That and "flow away" really does mean nothing.

Comment: @Patrice Asking about how to improve your post is always an acceptable question on meta, whether you received downvotes or not.

Comment: @patricksweeney see above.

Comment: @Patrice I understand your comment but to be appreciated make sure to add a reference [to the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/158100) of the joke and don't forget to add the ;) at the end. Otherwise new users will be utterly confused by our fun....

Comment: @rene but we hate fun.  Or something.